# Is it possible to stream video files using mms:// url in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, video-streaming

I'm developing an Application for Windows phone 7 using SilverLight.  Now I'm using `http://` to Stream videos in windows phone, but my requirement is to stream videos using `mms://` URL in my windows phone 7 Application.

I am not aware of the mms:// protocol, can you please tell me whether is it possible to stream video files using `mms://` url in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

This protocol is not currently supported for third party development on WP7.

Comment: Hi matt thanks for the reply.It means i can't develop  windows phone app which streams live videos using (mms URL).